# systemd-udevd fails to start triggerhappy upon boot

Tags: boot, systemd, raspberry-pi, udev, triggerhappy

When I boot my Raspberry Pi3 (4.14.34-v7+), I find the following error in the dmesg and other logs, after boot up. However, I am not currently using `triggerhappy`, so could probably disable that service. But in case I want to use in the future, I would like to know what is causing that error.

```
systemd-udevd[157]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
```

There are two entries in the systemd services:

```
systemctl status triggerhappy.service
systemctl status triggerhappy.socket
```

And the code trying to be executed seem to come from:
`/lib/udev/rules.d/60-triggerhappy.rules`:

**Why does this fail during boot?**
(It seem to run later though...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why:** This error is being caused by a combination of things:

**1)** The command `th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev` produces a `segfault`.  This seems to be because triggerhappy hasn't been patched to address a number of issues reported over the last 4 years...

- https://github.com/wertarbyte/triggerhappy/issues

**2)** Unfortunately, the error will still appear in syslog even if you disable triggerhappy Eg:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable triggerhappy.service
$ sudo systemctl disable triggerhappy.socket
```

This is because disabling triggerhappy doesn't remove the udev rules here: `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-triggerhappy.rules`.

**Solution** (If you're not using triggerhappy anyway - like on a headless system):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove triggerhappy
```

Comment: Are you sure that a segfault causes exit code 1?

Comment: The short answer is: No, I'm not sure if the process th-cmd segfaults after being launched during boot up.  Perhaps the process that launches th-cmd (systemd-udevd, I believe) reports exit code 1 after th-cmd is unsuccessful at doing whatever it's meant to do.  "th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev" segfaults when issued from the command line after boot.

Comment: Thanks! I had completely forgotten about this issue. Accepted

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @[Caleb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/355153/caleb-carroll) there unfortunately seems to be a long standing bug in the `triggerhappy` service. But the udev rule can be useful if you want the triggerhappy happy daemon to take account of events triggered by new event sources - which can come from devices that are connected to the machine during or after boot. To work around this bug you can replace the `RUN` line in the `60-triggerhappy.rules` file with the following:

```
        RUN+="/bin/systemctl restart triggerhappy"
```